# IntelliJ "Find Usages" and Maven artifacts

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Our team manages Java projects using Maven. We have a policy that all code on the `master` branch of a repository should:

1. itself have a `-SNAPSHOT` version (releases are created using the Maven Release plugin)
2. have Maven dependencies only on releases and never on `-SNAPSHOT`s.

This has an unfortunate consequence in IntelliJ IDEA (version 15, build 143.1821.5).    Suppose Maven artifact A depends on some release version of Maven artifact B, say `1.2.3`.  The current code for `B` on `master`, though, will be something like `1.2.4-SNAPSHOT`.  If I load the source for both `A` and `B` in IDEA, go to a class in `B` which is used in `A`, and do a `Find Usages` (Ctrl-click the class name or `Alt-7`), no results are found.  If, however, I navigate in the IDE to the decompiled class file for the `1.2.4` release and do `Find Usages`, it finds the usages in `A`.

I understand why this happens --- the `-SNAPSHOT` version of the code really isn't being used by `A` --- but this degree of pickiness makes `Find Usages` nearly useless across Maven artifacts.  However, I seem to remember at some point in the recent past IDEA's `Find Usages` wasn't so picky.  Unfortunately Googling hasn't turned up anyone else mentioning this problem or a mention of a change in IDEA behavior, so now we are thinking we just imagined the previous behavior.

So, does anyone know how to get IDEA to ignore version mismatches on Maven modules when doing `Find Usages`?  Was there some setting we had enabled before that we now can't find?

Comment: I'm not sure that Idea was ever not 'picky' about this as it is highly desirable. I have had similar configurations in the past (though I usually reserve master as the only non-snapshot branch, I often load a snapshot version of a dependency into intellij). The first thing I do is change the dependencies to reference the snapshot versions of the modules I've loaded -- because I want Idea to reference the code in the editor. To find these I go to the non-snapshot dependency in the 'External Libraries' in the project view, and search for usage of the classes in there, and navigate to their poms.

Comment: @EngineerDollery The behaviour may be "highly desirable" in some circumstances, but definitely not in all. For example, imagine I'm working on a main project with a library dependency, and I'm making changes to the library. I create a branch of the library from master and just check out the latest of the main project. If I want to quickly find where a particular library class is used, I now have to make a code change (and a new git branch) in the main project. It's not much hassle, but it's not something I'd immediately think of when casually hitting Alt+F7, with both projects in my workspace.

Comment: Your example is one of poor behaviour. If you're using dependency management then you are 'required' to maintain a list of dependencies and their versions. You describe working on a new version of a component, and to do that you 'must' update your dependency list. Your workspace doesn't enter into it -- it is a mental construct that has nothing to do with your code. If you really want that level of informal code-slinging start writing Node.JS (or php), because java+maven simply shouldn't work that way.

Comment: In my case, my project has many microservices with pinned versions of dependencies. The library is on a SNAPSHOT version so no services use the source code version of the library. When modifying the library, I want to find all usages of a certain class across all services and all dependency versions so I can evaluate what services I might want to upgrade to the new version of my library. So this functionality would be very useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing this incorrectly.

By definition, the MASTER branch should be a released version (no -SNAPSHOT).

You want to talk to your team and review your build and release processes.

Have a read about the git-flow branching model for some more information about branching strategies.